# Block matrices and their determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinants, block-matrices

For $n\in\Bbb{N}$, define three matrices $A_n(x,y), B_n$ and $M_n$ as follows:

(a) the $n\times n$ tridiagonal matrix $A_n(x,y)$ with main diagonal all $y$'s, superdiagonal all $x$'s and subdiagonal all $-x$'s. For example,
$$ A_4(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} y&x&0&0\\-x&y&x&0\\0&-x&y&x
\\0&0&-x&y\end{pmatrix}. $$

(b) the $n\times n$ antidigonal matrix $B_n$ consisting of all $1$'s. For example,
$$B_4=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

(c) the $n^2\times n^2$ block-matrix $M_n=A_n(B_n,A_n(1,1))$ or using the Kronecker product $M_n=A_n(1,0)\otimes B_n+I_n\otimes A_n(1,1)$.

> **Question.** What is the determinant of $M_n$?

**UPDATE.** For even indices, I conjecture that

> $$\det(M_{2n})=\prod_{j,k=1}^n\left[1+4\cos^2\left(\frac{j\pi}{2n+1}\right)+4\cos^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)\right]^2.$$

This would confirm what Philipp Lampe's "perfect square" claim.

Comment: I’m guessing you have an amazing conjectural answer?

Comment: I conjecture that the determinant of $M_n$ is a perfect square. I conjecture that the zeros of the characteristic polynomial of $M_n$ are complex numbers with real part $1$. Here is some [numerical experimentation](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=bhbugg) supporting the statements.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: Working on it.

Comment: @PhilippLampe: That is cool, thanks Perhaps proving your conjecture would also be interesting.

Comment: The conjectured formula for even indices might be linked to the grid graph $G_{2n,2n}$, that is, the graph with vertex set $[1,2n]\times[1,2n]\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ such that two points are connected by an edge if and only if the distance between them is $1$. We orient the graph as follows. Every horizontal edge is oriented to the west. Every vertical edge with an odd $x_1$-coordinate is oriented north and every vertical edge with an even $x_1$-coordinate is oriented south. Note that the orientation is Pfaffian since every inner face has $1$ clockwise and $3$ counterclockwise oriented arrows.

Comment: We arrange the vertices of $G_{2n,2n}$ in [topological order][2]. Let $A_{2n}$ be the signed adjacency matrix of $G_{2n,2n}$ with respect to the orientation, that is, $A_{jk}=-A_{kj}=1$ if the arrow is oriented $i\to j$. Note that $A_{2n}=M_{2n}-I_{4n^2}$ where $I_{4n^2}$ is the $4n^2\times 4n^2$ identity matrix.

Comment: A Theorem of Kasteleyn and Fisher--Temperley asserts that the number of perfect matching of $G_{2n,2n}$ is equal to
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\lvert \operatorname{det}\left(A_{2n}\right)\rvert}=\prod_{j,k=1}^n \left(4\cos^2\left(\frac{j\pi}{2n+1}\right)+4\cos^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)\right).
\end{align*} Why is this true? The main idea in the proof of the equality of the number of perfect matchings and the determinant is to note that every non-zero summand in the expansion of the determinant has the same sign due to the clever choice of signs.

Comment: As it is explained in Section 2.2 in Kenyon's [Lecture Notes](https://inis.iaea.org/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/38/098/38098203.pdf), the cosines arise essentially as the eigenvalues of a matrix. This matrix is a variation of $A_{2n}$ but it has entries $1,i$ instead of $\pm 1$.

Comment: Let $A=A_n(1,0)$, which has eigenvalues $2i\cos(j\pi/(n+1))$. Flip the order of the Kronecker products to get a block matrix where all blocks are polynomial in $A$ and therefore commute. The determinant is $\det(f(A))$ where $f$ is the characteristic polynomial of $-A_n(1,1)B_n$, which appears to be given by OEIS A152063. The determinant would then be the resultant of $f$ and the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flip the order of the Kronecker products to get $M'=A_n(I_n,I_n)+B_n\otimes T_n$, where $T_n=A_n(1,0)$. Note that $\det M=\det M'$. Since all blocks are polynomial in $A$, they commute, and therefore the determinant of $M'$ is $\det(f(T_n))$, where $f(x)=\det(A_n(1,1)+xB_n)$. That is, $f(x)=\det(B_n)\det(x+A_n(1,1)B_n)$ is $(-1)^{n\choose 2}$ times the characteristic polynomial of $H=-A_n(1,1)B_n$.

Let $t_n(x)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $T_n$. By repeated cofactor expansion on the first row, $t_n(x)=xt_{n-1}(x)+t_{n-2}(x)$. The initial conditions then imply that the $t_n$ is the $(n+1)^{th}$ Fibonacci polynomial. The roots of $t_n$ are $2i\cos(k\pi/(n+1))$ for $k=1,\dots,n$.

The eigenvalues of $H$ are worked out in ["The eigenvalues of some anti-tridiagonal Hankel matrices"](https://journalskuwait.org/kjs/index.php/KJS/article/view/2372). When $n$ is odd they are $1$ and $\pm\sqrt{3+2\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{n+1})}$ for $k=1,\dots,\frac{n-1}{2}$. When $n$ is even they are $\pm\sqrt{1+4\cos^2(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{n+1})}$ for $k=0,\dots,\frac{n}{2}-1$.

By a quick diagonalization argument $\det(f(T_n))$ is the resultant of $f$ and $t_n$. This plus some trig gives
$$
\det(M_{2n})=\prod_{j,k=1}^n\left[1+4\cos^2\left(\frac{j\pi}{2n+1}\right)+4\cos^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)\right]^2
$$
and
$$
\det(M_{2n-1})=\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\left[1+4\cos^2\left(\frac{j\pi}{2n}\right)\right]^2\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left[1+4\cos^2\left(\frac{j\pi}{2n}\right)+4\cos^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)\right]^2.
$$